# Oracle Text: query scoring with CTXCAT index?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

If a text column is indexed with a CTXSYS.CONTEXT index it can return a score showing how well the text matches the query.

```
create index ix on t(text) indextype is ctxsys.context parameters ('');
select id, score(1) from t where contains(text,'my query',1) > 0;
```

How can I see the score for text columns index with a CTXSYS.CTXCAT index?

```
create index ix on t(text) indextype is ctxsys.ctxcat parameters ('');
select id, ??? from t where catsearch(text, 'my query',null) > 0;
```

Comment: I see nothing in the documentation that states it's possible

Answer (score 1):

The score can only be accessed with a CONTENT index using a query like this

```
SELECT ID, TEXT,SCORE(1) FROM t WHERE CONTAINS(text, 'my query',1) > 0
ORDER BY SCORE(99) DESC;
```

By [Oracle 11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/ot11g-new-features-132182.pdf) everything you can do with a CTXCAT index you can do more with a CONTENT index.  Why not use that?

Edit: The op asks if CONTENT indexes must be synced.  Yes, this is correct.  I find the time and load factor to do this is entirely acceptable for smaller records sets.  Your mileage may vary based on record size.
Further reference:

- [Oracle how to](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/text/CreateIndexes/CreatingTextIndexes.html#section1s5)
- [Text index how to](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/full-text-indexing-using-oracle-text-9i.php)

Comment: My understanding is that a CTXCAT index doesn't need to call CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX while a CONTEXT index does.  Is this obsolete information?